# Bracha on Food for Life Ezekiel 4:9 Sprouted Grain Bread

Tags: halacha, food, blessing

Food for Life manufactures a bread under the Hashgacha of the Kaf-K called [Ezekiel 4:9 Sprouted Grain Bread](http://www.foodforlife.com/product-catalog/ezekiel-49/breads/120C6-organic-sprouted-whole-grain-flourless-bread)

This bread is flourless and has the following ingredients. Organic Sprouted Whole Wheat, Filtered Water, Organic Malted Barley, Organic Sprouted Whole Millet, Organic Sprouted Whole Barley, Organic Sprouted Whole Lentils, Organic Sprouted Whole Soybeans, Organic Sprouted Whole Spelt, Fresh Yeast, Sea Salt.

What Bracha should be made on this bread?

Comment: Btw, the gemorah says it's really nasty and only those who are forced to would eat it :)

Comment: @avi. I've got to see that! Where?

Comment: @HodofHod I'll have to ask my father and see if he remembers. He pointed it out to me one time while he was going through shas.

Comment: Eruvin 81a (I know this is a year and a half after you asked)

Comment: @HodofHod: Eruvin 81a (today's daf). Although another opinion there is that it's not the composition per se that makes it inedible, but the type of fuel that was to be used to bake it (see Ezek. 4:12).

Comment: Ping @avi as well.

Comment: What does it mean that the bread is flourless?  Is the wheat and barley not made into flour before baking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[From the Star-K](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-InsightsFromTheInstitute-Fall11.htm#_ftn1):

- [Kollel Eretz Hemda says](http://www.ou.org/torah/tt/5766/vayigash66/print.htm) "it's either hamotzee or shehakol, and we're inclined to say it's shehakol."
- [Kof-K says it's hamotzee](http://www.thehalacha.com/attach/Volume4/Issue17.pdf). (pdf)
- Rabbi Heinemann shlit'a (and thus Star-K policy) says it's hamotzee.

Personally, unless I hear of other authorities saying it's shehakol, I call that a hamotzee.

Comment: +1. I wonder whether _Kollel Eretz Hemda_ would require _birchas hamazon_ (if one was sated and drank) because of _safek d'oraysa_.

Comment: Both links broken. I assume the second one is same as in GG’s answer.

Answer (score 7):

https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol4Issue17.pdf

> Ezekiel Bread is Hamotzei and Pas Yisroel. For  more on this topic
>   email mlebovits@kof-k.org