# Is a metzorah oleh l'regel?

Tags: halacha, travel, chagim-holidays, yerushalayim-jerusalem, tzaraas-negaim

A metzorah has to sit outside the city (Mishna Keilim 1:7). Does this mean that he is exempt from the commandment to be oleh l'regel in yerushalayim?

Comment: A Metzorah has to stay away from the makom Hamikdash ,so if he broke out with tzarras right before the regel then why would he be allowed to go?

Comment: Is this really [tag:halacha] lemaaseh?

Comment: @DoubleAA nowhere in the tag description does it say "lema'aseh" (or any version of that). Besides, other than the torah-parshanut questions, what on this site isn't halacha?

Comment: @Vram Kegon http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16498/759

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Rambam rules in [Chagigah 2:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/9202.htm) that someone who is tamei is exempt from ri'iyah. A metzora' would seem to be included in this category.

Comment: exempt or forbidden?

Comment: @cyclops Someone who is tamei is Biblicly forbidden to enter the mikdash. Are you asking what would happen if he did so anyway?

Comment: i'm asking if he would/should go to yerushalayim to sleep over, not to the mikdash

Comment: @cyclops I'm not sure what the point of his doing that would be, as I'm not aware of any obligation to do so. But even so, the Rambam rules in Biat Mikdash 3:8 that a metzora gets lashes for entering Yerushalayim, and two sets for entering Har HaBayit.

Comment: I hope this answer doesn't [*fall victim*](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6260/what-are-the-limits-of-mesira#comment35222_16474)

Comment: @Vram Me too, although I don't see how it would be controversial.

Comment: @DoubleAA http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/988/sefirat-haomer-tag#comment2281_988

Comment: @Vram I _was_ kind of confused why there was the [tag:halacha] tag was on this question...